# How to persist DOM changes applied via CSS transitions

Tags: css, dom, css-transitions, css-transforms

Is it possible and how to persist DOM elements transformation applied via CSS transition. The case is simple animate a DOM element with CSS and on animation complete I want to persist the DOM element in the complete animation state and remove the CSS style with which I have applied the transformations.

Comment: Reset all style to default at the latest keyframe? 99% = animation end. 100% = reset styles.